# AS3: How can I fire events when a property is changed in a über class?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, event-handling

I have a TextField inside a Sprite and I always want the alpha of the TextField to be equal to the alpha of the sprite. How can i subscribe to the changes made in the Sprite? I guess i need to fire a PropertychangeEvent some how, but I can't see that sprite supports this out of the box?

```
class TextWidget extends Sprite{  
  private var textfield:TextField;    
  public function TextWidget(){  
    textfield = new TextField();  
    textfield.alpha = this.alpha;  //does'n help  
    addChild(textField);  
??  
  this.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, updateAlpha);  
??  
  }
  private function updateAlpha(event:PropertychangeEvent):void{  
    textfield.alpha = this.alpha;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: When posting code, please indent each line 4 spaces so that it becomes nicely formatted and colorized, makes it much easier for us to read :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to create a derived class of the sprite and override the alpha property

```
/**
 * ...
 * @author Andrew Rea
 */
public class CustomSprite extends Sprite
{

    public static const ALPHA_CHANGED:String = "ALPHA_CHANGED";

    public function CustomSprite() 
    {

    }

    override public function get alpha():Number { return super.alpha; }

    override public function set alpha(value:Number):void 
    {
        super.alpha = value;

        dispatchEvent(new Event(CustomSprite.ALPHA_CHANGED));
    }
}
```

Another way would simply be to set the textfield alpha whenever the alpha setter of the parent sprite is hit, as shown above just without the event.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to override the alpha setter and using the value passed in for the TextField as well.

```
public override function set alpha(value:Number):void {
    super.alpha = value;
    textField.alpha = value;
}
```